# How can I pass a SSL certificate to Nowin when using Nancy

Tags: c#, owin, nancy, nowin

So I am using [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) with [Nowin](https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin).

The beauty of using Nowin is I don't have to mess around with various Windows commands to set up a simple web server. According to the Nowin readme I can configure SSL using the following line

```
builder.SetCertificate(new X509Certificate2("certificate.pfx", "password"));
```

However, when using Nancy I don't seem to have access to this Server builder class. Everything seems to happen magically behind the scenes.

Any ideas how I can pass the certificate through to Nowin?

Comment: Have you checked [this link](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/417740/Using-Nancy-with-Nowin-%28without-MS-Owin-) out about using Nancy with nowin?

Comment: Wouldn't you set the owin environment variable `ssl.ClientCertificate`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the Nancy.Owin package installed.
2. Use code like this to start the server up:

.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nancy.Owin;
using Nowin;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myNancyAppFunc = NancyMiddleware.UseNancy()(NancyOptions options =>
        {
            // Modify Nancy options if desired;

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });

        using (var server = ServerBuilder.New()
            .SetOwinApp(myNancyAppFunc)
            .SetEndPoint(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080))
            .SetCertificate(new X509Certificate2("certificate.pfx", "password"))
            .Build()
        )
        {
            server.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Running on 8080");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this document](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Accessing-the-client-certificate-when-using-SSL), it says the following:

#### Configuration of OWIN

It'll just be there if the host sends it on.

If you use IIS as a host. You'll need to do the same [config as with Aspnet](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Accessing-the-client-certificate-when-using-SSL#configuration-of-aspnet). And you'll need an OWIN Aspnet host that supports the ClientCertificate. The one in the [OWIN demo in Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Owin/SimpleOwinAspNetHost.cs) does. The one by [@prabirshrestha](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/simple-owin) also does.

In the OWIN Demo, check [this line](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Owin/SimpleOwinAspNetHost.cs#L215):

```
if (request.ClientCertificate != null && request.ClientCertificate.Certificate.Length != 0)
        {
            env[OwinConstants.ClientCertificate] = new X509Certificate(request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);
        }
```

Hope it helps you, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow by the way described in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451439.aspx
At first you are creating web server according with Nowin documentation and after that you are adding Nancy as pipeline component. I tested this way with NowingSample (from Nowin package) and it works.